# OnPrepareFile Method returns a constructor when using FilePond 4.11

Tags: filepond

I have been on this for days now, am checking the mime type and only allowing CSV file, I want to see the content of the file upon passing validation so I can print with PapaParse on the screen. Using the onPrepareFile method returns a constructor and not the file that FilePond grabbed. If I print the 'output' param I see the details of the file so I know FilePond grabbed it. Is this a bug in the library or am I doing this the wrong way?

How can I see the attached file and do something with it without sending it to the server?

codepen below:

```
onpreparefile: (file, output) => {
            console.log('print file to console', file);
        }
```

https://codepen.io/jorgecas99/pen/abOzpKX?editors=0001

Comment: without a custom transform plugin (the default one only transforms images) onprepare file isn't suitable for csv files so not sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks Rik. I simply wanted to use filepond to grab and validate the file since the UI is super slick but just for that. I need to preview the csv using papaparse on the client side so they can do some mapping and then I will upload the csv as JSON to the server. You saying there is no way to grab the file attached once the filepond instance has it?

Comment: You can use `getFile` to access the file item, the file item has a `file` property that is the file object.

Comment: Thanks Rik. Does the file has to be uploaded to the server in order to get access to the raw file? I tried your approach and all I can access is the metadata for the file and not its content. Can you provide a jsfiddle or codepen to see it working please?